# Скрипт не срабатывает после подгрузки контента Ajax'ом

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

Подгружается контент (посты) и для него данный код не работает. Как правильно заставить скрипт реагировать на подгруженные элементы?

```
var $button = $('.button2');
var $modal = $('#modal');
var $modal_target = $('#modal_target');

$button.click(function() {

var id = $(this).data('id');

$.ajax({
 url: ajaxurl,
 data: {
  'action' : 'fetch_modal_content',
  'id' : id
  },
success:function(data) {
  $modal_target.html(data);

}
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать делегирование. Чтобы немного увеличить производительность, рекомендую указать вместо `$('body')`, родителя  "поближе". Например "врапер", в котором лежат эти кнопки.

```
var $button = $('.button2');
var $modal = $('#modal');
var $modal_target = $('#modal_target');

$('body').on('click', '.button2', function() {

var id = $(this).data('id');

$.ajax({
 url: ajaxurl,
 data: {
  'action' : 'fetch_modal_content',
  'id' : id
  },
success:function(data) {
  $modal_target.html(data);

}
});

});
```

Comment: Попробовал, контент почему-то не весь подтягивается у постах, которые подгружаются